# Disambiguating place vs Manner of articulation

Tags: phonetics, phonemes, articulation

Some aspects of the IPA chart are not intuitive to me. I tend to think of "place of articulation" as "where a sound is produced" and "manner of articulation" as "how a sound is produced".

Is this a useful understanding or does it reduce the meaning of the rows and columns in the IPA chart?

Also: Is there an image that combines place and/or manner with an x-ray view of the speech organs? That'd help me better understand those terms. The examples I find online don't correspond exactly to the IPA chart so they're often more distracting than helpful. For example, the image below only has 9 places of articulation mentioned, whereas the IPA has 11.

[image]

It'd be awesome if there was an image or images like this that included both place and manner, but maybe it'd be too complicated.  Any input/advice on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't represent a manner graphically because... it's a manner, not a thing. By the way, you better think of manner in terms of "type of obstacle". Indeed, all sounds need a stream of air to be articulated. The articulation consists in interrupting such stream in various ways. Sometimes you get a complete occlusion which prevents the air from moving at all (so, you have the **stops**). Some other times, you let flow some amount of air; this might be a **fricative** or, e.g., a **lateral**. In a lateral, the obstacle is incomplete because some residual air stream flows through openings between the tongue sides and the palate. Such an approach explains why lateral is a manner rather than a place, notwithstanding that the term has a "location" in it. Similarly for **nasals**: the air flows through the nasal cavities, so that the obstacle is not as complete as in stops. **Vowels** are just another type of obstacle, i.e. a null obstacle.

Comment: I think the real reason why you can't represent manner in such a chart is that it requires a 3-d movie – it refers to dynamic properties, not static ones.

Comment: One funny animated illustration is to be found here:
http://svg-whiz.com/svg/linguistics/theCreepyMouth.svg

Comment: Lulz. Supraglottal place entails oral, laryngeals are all nasal. Glad they cleared that up.